# Print picture from a terminal

Tags: command-line, printing, ubuntu-mate

I would like to print a picture from a terminal.

I use Gimp. I could not find anything using a search.

Comment: You can convert the image to PDF with the `convert` command from `imagemagick` toolset. And then print the pdf file with the famous `lp` command. But take care of the image size, it may have to be resized before converted to pdf.

Comment: @cmak.fr Consider moving your suggestion to an answer -  maybe with an example?

Comment: @cmak.fr I found out that lp will print pngs without converting them.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using CUPS then according to the page at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372379/what-file-formats-does-cups-support "CUPS understands many different types of files directly, including text, PostScript, PDF, and image files.

The actual file types it will print seem to be somewhat dependant on your system. This answer gives more details. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447656/277042

To print a png file from the commandline

```
lp file.png -d printername
```

lp has various options to give more control over the actual output (scaling etc)